# Laravel Passport: Unauthenticated Message when asking for User Information

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-passport

I want to implement Passport authentication in Laravel. this is the register function:

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('name', 'email', 'password');

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:120|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error'=> $validator->errors()]);
        }

        $user = User::create(['name' => $request->name, 'email' => $request->email, 'password' => bcrypt($request->password)]);

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){ 

         $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
         $data['id'] = $user->id;
         $data['name'] = $user->name;
         $data['phone'] = $user->phone;
         $data['token'] = $user->createToken('API')->accessToken;

         return response()->json([
            'success'=> true,
            'data'=> $data
         ]);

     }
      return response()->json([
        'success'=> false,
         'data'=> $response
      ]);
     }
```

and this is my routes:

```
Route::post('register', 'Api\AuthController@register');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->user());
});
```

I want to display the user information in postman, and this is the request header to the url: http://127.0.0.1:8004/api/user:

```
Accept:application/json
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiOThjYjM0YjkzOWJhMzczMDEwMGI0NmEyNTBhOGEzYTc5MTAyMjI1M2E2OTM0OGY0NGU1YWU4Njg3MzZkYmVlZjNlNzI1MDNiZTRhMjE5NGUiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODQ1NDczMDcsIm5iZiI6MTU4NDU0NzMwNywiZXhwIjoxNjE2MDgzMzA3LCJzdWIiOiI1NyIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.GcqelFT2d3kKi8fR2vNbgMB1Fe_sQjrd2Mb3cRQLbS20IR_445bcTbcl17yKJrldboFktobeSIHx1GQENIzQbO0RStysmisiKuLk8eoXUvNVJq3t1bpZrjPBiNEGDRPqezq5VEsGhotVgbKRLK1gbVHwvE7mtSuGQTp9nIf6PEsmiJLsGmUJ0GdCmWXXLvJ0dBac1DZ_KauppDs_Lymx9SEXgzTDW60rpYrwHNbbaLfa6wdW3M5tUZM3vMRcKhCgYitvK_DfttKHcWqvEX8_lZT0h5GcQSsori_K8Lj_ynKfjrTfbodUKzT4kDZ8z-RnE4-SgG75LWDeqcpDRhuDmiL0KTIzwtrNFtU0NEo-v0t6dTkAuJCl1ZnTT72sLZoI6rsTPHtNKIDxwN9VrXiTU5pxGEc6ju5e30NQnkjBRjMRsVIcCHR-WohObuWkZOGRq-RP5on3oiLe2VGk0PENXXziMX3D5urpLWK3WR-ZY0Bz3fKitgE8TFaT1cOMSyK6d3zskUEdMjDyLCxbS7vKhmNuAy2moOj7f7DI9yr8XNeyF00WJKw0WJi76XX_Y06O-VtNhqzgeEyu6QM6qRivpBBcj-WkdbSTmveNZlSqAesLm6WD8qWKc9FR-S_41fCc2qLEY_VOotSA8tOYASVKpdsvj2liTbbMH9905HQJe-o
Content-Type:application/json
```

but the result is always:

> {
>       "message": "Unauthenticated." 
>   }

How could I display user information? thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
Auth::attempt($credentials)
```

to

```
Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credentials)
```

Comment: "Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist."